# OpenID Connect flow with multiple identity providers?

Tags: security, jwt, openid, identityserver4

So I have a .NET Web application that can authenticate via OpenID Connect to multiple identity providers (some internal some external). These providers give me "id tokens".

I also have multiple REST APIs that I'd like to protect. Each of these really only needs the user id as we have an internal authorisation mechanism.

However, it's considered bad practice to pass the id_token to the APIs, and really I should get a access token from somewhere. The question is, where's the best place to get the tokens from? Do I really need something like IdentityServer for this, or should I produce a simple REST API that can unwrap an id_token and wrap the username back up as an access_token with the correct audience?

In fact should each API have its own endpoint that turns an id_token into an access_token for that API? Is that what embedding IdentityServer in each API does?

Sorry for the confusion, but it seems so tempting in this case to just pass the id_token through to each API!

Comment: Note I don't want to have a central access token issuer as it doesn't know all the APIs that exist